# How to trigger to Laravel failed_jobs if jobs received 400 response code?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to asking how to trigger Laravel jobs to be inserted to failed_jobs table?

As I using the jobs to hit an external API, there might be failure response. In this case I want to insert the failed jobs when the response is 400 or something bad happened.

Here is my code

```
if($responseCode == 400){
  // trigger to failed jobs
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Throw an unhandled exception from the running Job, it will go to `failed_jobs` automagically.

More details: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have added an Exception
`throw new \Exception('Something went wrong while sending WhatsApp.');`
but found nothing in failed_jobs table

Comment: Can you confirm if jobs are getting executed? Are you sure exception is not caught?